# Переименование таблицы pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

Как переименовать таблицу в `pymysql` пробовал

```
one = input('')
two = input('')
cur.execute('RENAME TABLE %s TO %s', (one, two))
s = "ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s"
cur.execute(s, (one, two))
```

в обоих случаях выдавало ошибку:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''asd' RENAME TO 'primer'' at line
>   1")

Comment: Кавычки кривые.

Comment: @Akina не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы экономить, сперва соберите запрос в переменной, а потом эту переменную отдавайте в cur.execute. А в серединке - выведите текст запроса и посмотрите, что не так... Должно получиться `RENAME TABLE asd TO primer` или ``RENAME TABLE `asd` TO `primer` ``

Comment: @Akina не мне нужно чтобы вместо значений `asd` и `primer`  в последующем были значения которые вводит пользователь. Так как вы показали у меня получилось реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на просторах [английского stackoverflow ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46107291/8206722) ответ оказался достаточно банален

```
one = input('Введите название таблицы которой нужно поменять название\n')
two = input('На какой название хотите поменять?\n')
cur.execute("RENAME TABLE %s TO %s" % (one, two))
```

Или

```
one = input('Введите название таблицы которой нужно поменять название\n')
two = input('На какой название хотите поменять?\n')
s = "ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s"
cur.execute(s % (one, two))
```